# how to render selected date when I select date from calendar using primefaces?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

Selected date should be displayed in outputText when I select date from calendar control of primefaces. I have written code for this but not worked.

```
<p:calendar mode="popup" showOn="both" mindate="15-06-2012" pattern="dd-MM-yyyy" effect="fadeIn">
       <p:ajax event="keyup" update="out1"/>
</p:calendar><br/><br/><hr/>
<h:outputText id="out1" value="#{sampleBean.selectedDate}"/>
```

Comment: Did you try with render attribute? something like render="out1" in p:ajax?

Comment: <p:ajax> have not render attribute.

Comment: Sorry! my mistake. I work on rich:faces, I think you need to use "update". See this link http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6028

Comment: I have already used it.But not worked.

Comment: Give me solution Please.

Comment: <p:calendar value="#{sampleBean.selectedDate}" /> .... and then ..... Change <p:ajax event="keyup" update="out1"/> ..... to .... <p:ajax event="onchange" update="out1"/>

Comment: onchange event is incorrect. it is not supported

Comment: onchange is supported. Also, as an alternative, we can use mouse events also.

Answer (score 3):

From your question what i understand is that you want to show the date in ouput which you selected.

for this in your

```
<p:calendar..... code
```

add a statement of

```
value="#{sampleBean.selectedDate}" update=":out1"
```

This way the selected value will be saved in the selectedDate attribute of your sampleBean.

```
<h:outputText id="out1" value="#{sampleBean.selectedDate}"/>
```

Comment: Also when asking a question please specify what you are currently working on like jsf version, primefaces,richfaces e.t.c version and your server...

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish but the value returned from the calendar goes to the "value" tag wich is missing, why can't you simply use something like:

```
<p:calendar value="#{sampleBean.selectedDate}" id="calId"  mode="popup" showOn="both" mindate="15-06-2012" pattern="dd-MM-yyyy" effect="fadeIn" />
```

This should (according to docs and [Showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/calendarBasic.jsf;jsessionid=0C951B025110F26A32EA972969E1FE0A)) should render n input with the calendar just fine...